I'm making ACV and got a jar of pectin I believe
I started a jar vinegar from store bought ORGANIC apples about six months ago. are used clean jar and utensils. I kept it in a cool, dark place, but forgot to continuously stir it. When I took it out this morning it had greenish blue mold on top which I removed, and is very thick and off-white color. It doesn't look bad but looks like I have full jar of pectin with little to no vinegar. This is only the second time I've made it and it came out great the first time. Is it pectin, the mother that got two large? Should I use some of that and try to start a new batch or try to strain it? I have a lot of questions. I don't think I can add a picture.
